# Loop ordering and -ftree-vectorize

Tags: c, loops, vectorization

I have four nested for loops as follows:

```
const size_t nMax = 300 ; double acc = 0 ;

for( size_t i=0 ; i<nMax ; i++ ) {
   for( size_t j=0 ; j<nMax ; j++ ) {
      for( size_t k=0 ; k<nMax ; k++ ) {
         for( size_t l=k ; l<nMax ; l++ ) {
            acc += 1.0 ;
         }
      }
   }
}
printf( "Accumulator is %f\n", acc ) ;
```

Compiling with `gcc` (version 5.4.0) and `-O3`, the code completes in 5.188 seconds. Now, if I reorder the loops

```
const size_t nMax = 300 ; double acc = 0 ;

for( size_t k=0 ; k<nMax ; k++ ) {
   for( size_t l=k ; l<nMax ; l++ ) {
      for( size_t i=0 ; i<nMax ; i++ ) {
         for( size_t j=0 ; j<nMax ; j++ ) {
            acc += 1.0 ;
         }
      }
   }
}
printf( "Accumulator is %f\n", acc ) ;
```

and once again compile with `-O3`, the code runs in 3.500 seconds. I'm uncertain why this is the case: I get that in the second code segment, the loop over `l` checks the value of the outer loop for the start condition `nMax * nMax` times less frequently than in the first code segment, but it seems unlikely (?) that this would yield such a significant performance hit.

Compiling with `-O2` makes both codes execute in the same amount of time (roughly 5.2 seconds), so I managed to track down `-ftree-vectorize` as the flag that can be used in conjunction with `-O2` to recover the performance difference.

Why can `-ftree-vectorize` optimise the second code segment and not the first?

**Edit**

Added the assembly versions of the code with `gcc -O2 -ftree-vectorize`. I'm fairly ignorant on assembler, so can't really claim to understand a great deal. Here's the first (slow) segment:

```
    .file   "code_one.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC2:
    .string "Accumulator is %f\n"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB3:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB3:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB38:
    .cfi_startproc
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movapd  .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
.L2:
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
.L8:
    movhpd  .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    movl    $300, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    subq    $1, %rax
    addpd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    jne .L3
    addl    $1, %edx
    cmpl    $150, %edx
    jne .L6
    movdqa  %xmm0, %xmm2
    addq    $1, %rsi
    cmpq    $300, %rsi
    psrldq  $8, %xmm2
    addpd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    jne .L8
    addq    $1, %rcx
    cmpq    $300, %rcx
    jne .L2
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC2, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    __printf_chk
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE38:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE3:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE3:
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align 16
.LC1:
    .long   0
    .long   1072693248
    .long   0
    .long   1072693248
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

and the second (fast) version:

```
    .file   "code_two.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC2:
    .string "Accumulator is %f\n"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB3:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB3:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB38:
    .cfi_startproc
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    $300, %ecx
    movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
.L2:
    movl    $300, %esi
.L8:
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    addq    $1, %rax
    addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    cmpq    $300, %rax
    jne .L3
    addq    $1, %rdx
    cmpq    $300, %rdx
    jne .L6
    subq    $1, %rsi
    jne .L8
    subq    $1, %rcx
    jne .L2
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC2, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    __printf_chk
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE38:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE3:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE3:
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC1:
    .long   0
    .long   1072693248
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Check assembly language?

Comment: @mch Uh, sorry, oversaw that...

Comment: Added the assembly versions.